# What are some things that Webmasters should be preparing for or doing in response to the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: security, traffic

*This is a [community wiki](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) intended for our users to be able to share ideas as to what might be helpful to Webmasters during the COVID-19 pandemic.*

As many of you are aware, there's been a shift all across the world towards people working, learning, and shopping from home or in isolation, which brings new challenges for those who manage and operate websites, such as sharp increases in traffic, increases in security concerns, notifications to address your website/business's response, etc…

We'd like to hear from the community as to what are some of the things you've been planning, have implemented, or think might be helpful for others to do. There are no right or wrong answers, so feel free to add answers or edit to improve them.

We hope that everyone is staying healthy and safe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gary Illyes from Google says](https://www.reddit.com/r/TechSEO/comments/fobx9o/client_taking_site_down_due_to_coronavirus_best/) that Google is working on guidance for e-commerce sites that need to temporarily suspend business because of Covid-19:

> We're going to put up some more thorough do's and don't's, but in the meantime, closing the cart and putting up a message that explains to the user what's happening should be the way to go if you're planning the closure will last a long time. Anything else, redirects, 503s, etc, will have unwanted effects on the site from SEO perspective if lasts for more than just a couple days.

John Graham Cumming, CTO of CloudFlare, reports seeing a 10-30% increase in traffic (as of 3-26-2020), and is providing a webinar on [The Big Surge: How to build a more resilient and available web infrastructure](https://www.cloudflare.com/webinars/planning-for-increased-infrastructure-resilience-and-uptime/):

> Internet usage around the world is shifting as a result of COVID-19.
>   We are seeing an increase of 10-30% traffic across the board. As
>   companies face a sudden surge in traffic, it is important that they
>   ensure the availability of critical systems that serve their customers
>   and employees.

Answer (score 2):

I run a web hosting business.  I have always been pretty relaxed about quotas and such, but now I am loosening up about payments.

I am fortunate that I have a bunch of supportive customers who appreciate the great customer service I give them.  I emphasise to them that we can work out almost anything as long as they communicate with me.  If I don't know that they are facing a challenge I can't support them.

Ultimately it is in both my business interests and as a good human to do what I can.